# How can I highlight the top item in a custom scrollable list in Flutter, ensuring it stays active while scrolling?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-listview

I'm working on a Flutter app, and I need to create a custom scrollable list. The list should have a unique feature where the top item is always highlighted, even as the user scrolls through the list. It's important to note that the list items can have varying heights. How can I implement this behavior in my Flutter app with snapping effect?

I've been working on creating a custom scrollable list in Flutter, but I'm not sure how to implement the specific behavior of keeping the top item highlighted as the user scrolls through the list.

I've explored the built-in Flutter widgets like ListView, CustomScrollView, and others, but I couldn't find a straightforward solution to achieve this effect. I also experimented with various packages and custom code, but none of my attempts provided the desired outcome.

Comment: Have you thought of using a ListView embedded inside a Column? The first child of the column should be the first item in the list and the ListView contains the remainder of the list. Wrap the ListView inside Expanded.

Comment: @RoslanAmir Thank you for the advice, but unfortunately, this option doesn't suit me. I won't be able to create a beautiful animation of element transition during scrolling. I'm thinking that I need to come up with something using ScrollController, but I haven't figured out exactly what yet.